# Centralized management of many single-tenant instances

Tags: software-as-a-service, devops, multitenancy, monitoring

Designing a SaaS application that will be used by multiple business customers (tenants). Decided to use the [single tenant model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/isv/application-tenancy) - a single instance of the application and database is deployed for each customer.
[image: single tenant model]

The problem deals with monitoring and managing the instances. We can easily create an admin portal (for CRUD operations) that runs in each instance. However, we want to create a *centralized admin portal* that can show aggregated data from all instances and perform data changes on all instances.
For example, the regular admin portal shows a table of 50 users in one instance. The centralized admin portal needs to show all 500 users in all instances.
When performing bulk updates, the regular admin portal can update 50 users, while the centralized admin portal needs to update all 500 users in one operation.

How would you implement a centralized admin portal for this single-tenant architecture? Is there a design pattern suitable for that problem? Or any useful open-source projects?

Comment: Even if you built a system to query the various instances and their data stores, how do you handle the fact that they could be running different versions of the application or variations in the data schemas? If you intend to keep them updated together, then why have multiple instances? It seems like these requirements are at odds.

Comment: We need multiple database instances because of legal topics and regulations in our field. We don't run different versions or variations - all are the same.

Comment: I highly doubt that there are laws or regulations that require you to have multiple application instances with their own disjoint databases. This could be your interpretation of the laws or regulations, but I doubt it is the only interpretation and a multi-tenant solution would be permitted with appropriate controls in place.

Comment: Our customers are under data sovereignty regulations that specify where the physical machines storing data must reside. That's why we must use separate databases.

Comment: That is a very different problem and doesn't require multiple instances of the application. You're choosing to implement data sovereignty using multiple instances. You can associate a database in a geographic area with a particular node based on tenant or user while running a single instance multi-tenant application. You are shifting your complexity, but to one that is probably more readily addressed by existing solutions.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this idea? I'd like to consider it

Comment: I don't have anything handy, but the short story is that you have a primary "application database" that has information about where tenants are stored. You can then globally distribute your databases, using the tenant information (and likely configuration files) to be able to open connections to the right database. It does add complexity, but a different kind of complexity than deploying N application instances. You would deploy 1 application instance that would handle any kind of data updates and migrations.

Comment: @Alex And yet it's somehow okay for admins to copy that data onto separate machines that don't meet the sovereignty requirements?

Comment: @user253751 No, the data isn't copied anywhere. The admin portal is about viewing and modifying the data.

Comment: @ThomasOwens your suggestion still includes multiple databases. So what is the solution to run queries across all of them at once?

Comment: @Alex ... so copying it to the admin portal computer and back

Comment: @Alex You talk about users. Users and tenants would be in a centralized application database. Do you need to query other types of data? Depending on the nature of the data, you may be able to put aggregate or reporting data in the application database or a cache system and run your admin queries against that. Either way, I think you should update the question to better reflect the actual problem and why some solutions don't work.

Comment: I don't think there is a design pattern for this. There might be a tool, though. Don't reinvent the wheel unless you need to. Tool recommendations are off-topic for this site, however.